# How to know the dimension of swf file without Flash?

Tags: html, windows, flash

I've a swf file and i want to embed this file into HTML page but i don't know the exact dimension of swf . Windows XP file properties doesn't show the dimension and I don't have Adobe Flash software. Then how can i know the Dimension.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a collection of utilities for working with SWF files called [SWFTOOLS](http://www.swftools.org/). You can grab the Windows binary from the [Download page](http://www.swftools.org/download.html).

One of the tools in this package is `swfdump`, which can tell you the dimension of an SWF file. It also can produce the proper HTML code for embedding (output from my Linux box):

```
# swfdump -X flash.swf
-X 724
# swfdump -Y flash.swf
-Y 147
# swfdump -E flash.swf
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
 data="flash.swf" width="724" height="147">
<param name="movie" value="flash.swf"/>
<param name="play" value="true"/>
<param name="quality" value="high"/>
</object>
```

Comment: swftools installed a pdf2swf converter ... not a swf-inspection utility ... I downloaded: `swftools-2013-04-09-1007.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Open it from your hard drive using Flash player -double click it- and then use [JR Screen Ruler](http://www.spadixbd.com/freetools/jruler.htm) to look at its dimensions. If it happens to open in full screen mode just press ESC ;)

Answer (score 1):

SWF files have a header right at the start where the frame size in twips is stored as a RECT structure. When the image is played back at 100% scaling, there are 20 twips to a pixel.

See [this document](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf/pdf/swf_file_format_spec_v10.pdf) for details.